# Parallel 4221-BCD counter on D-triggers

Tags: digital-logic, counter

I`m new on it, consider it please. I have to build a 4-bit counter in 4221 bcd using D triggers. Learning about triggers, and seeking for completed schemes, I made the next one:

Took the classic binary counter(it's subtractive , but nevermind)
[image]

And put there code converter from bin to 4221-bcd, and got complete 4221 subtractive  counter.

[image]

I give it to my teacher, and She said, that

1. it should be initially in 4221 bcd, not binary+converter
2. I had to make a synchronous counter

My questions:

1) Is it possible to build a D-trigger based-only **synchronous** counter?

2) How do you, think, what did She mean, saying "initially in 4221, without converters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure what the teacher is expecting from you then you really should ask the teacher. However, my **guess** is that the values in the flip-flops themselves are supposed to represent the counter value in 4221. So you need to design a logic circuit that properly determines the next state of each flip-flop, given the current state of each flip-flop.

If the counter is supposed to be **synchronous**, then the clock input of every flip-flop must be connected to the main clock input signal, not to the output of another flip-flop.

Is it possible? Sure.

Comment: "then the clock input of every flip-flop must be connected to the main clock input signal, not to the output of another flip-flop" and that's all?

Comment: I understood how it work, and what does my teacher want. But now I don't know how to build a logic to work in my 4221 code. In case of code converter I make a Carnage maps, and the functions. What should I do now?

Comment: You make new Karnaugh maps. These maps will determine the next state of a specific flip-flop given the current state of all four flip-flops. This "next state" signal is used as the D input of the specific flip-flop. So, you need to create and analyze four, 4-input Karnaugh maps.

Comment: Can You specify, what functions I should calculate? In previous it was x1(A,B,C,D) for example. What now?

Comment: The Q outputs of the flip-flops are used directly as the outputs of the entire circuit. The functions you must calculate are the functions that determine the desired next state of each individual flip-flop given the current state of all flip-flops. Make a truth table with ten rows. The 4 "input" bits in each row are the current Q outputs of the flip-flops, the 4 "output" bits in each row are the desired next value for each flip-flop. Convert each output column to a K-map and solve.

Comment: 4 rows for current Q, 4 for the next, what should be two another?

Comment: If I understand You correctly, I need to calculate functions $$Q1_{next}(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)\space Q2_{next}(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)\space etc.$$

Comment: What should I do with them?

Comment: Q_next should come to D input, probably